# Perf top reports symbol "__cpuidle_text_start" consuming 87% CPU time

Tags: linux, power-management, kernel, c

I have powersave (C-states) disabled in BIOS and in the kernel config, however, CONFIG_CPU_IDLE is enabled, and related "__cpuidle_text_start" takes too much CPU time, while I am not really sure what it actually does.
Is this a correct behaviour, should I disable said option?

[image: perf top output]